# Nexus One Android Debugging in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

I can't get Ubuntu 9.10 to recognize the Nexus One as a debug device.  I tried following the instructions found here but they are not working: http://alan.lamielle.net/2010/01/22/nexus-one-usb-in-ubuntu-9-10

Anyone know of a link or know how to get the Nexus One to debug correctly in Ubuntu 9.10?

Comment: I am using eclipse and seeing a lot of ???? in the serial number of the device as Macarse suggested! what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I feel like an idiot.  Somewhere down the line I turned off my debug settings, so no matter what I did with the udev rules, it wouldn't show up.  Now that I turned it on, it's working.  Thanks to all who tried to help.  :/

Answer (score 2):

the id is "18d1" not "0bb4" for Nexus One.

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666"

Comment: highlight for LOWER-case `18d1` instead of `18D1`

Answer (score 1):

You might try `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"` instead of the line listed on that page. That is the rule that I use, and Ubuntu 9.10 amd64 recognizes it correctly.

You may also need to play around with the actual number in the front of the filename (shown as `51-android.rules` in the linked-to page). Mine is `50-android.rules`. The number controls the order in which the rules are applied, AFAIK.

Also, be sure reload `udev` (as shown on that page) and restart the `adb` daemon (via `adb kill-server`, then `adb start-server`).

Comment: I've tried almost every combination I can think of, nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

You went through [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/developing/device.html)?

- Add `android:debuggable="true"` in your manifest.
- On the device, go to the home screen, press MENU, select Applications > Development, then enable USB debugging.

After this, follow CommonsWare explanation. You might need to unplug/plug for it to work.

Comment: Tried it about a dozen times.  My G1 works just fine, Nexus One is not working at all.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? When choosing where to run do you see "????" in your Serial Number column?

Comment: No, when I try to run in eclipse it just opens an virtual device.  It doesn't even recognize that a phone is attached.